# Загрузка файлов на сервер через Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Нужно на сервер передать несколько файлов ( 1-4 видео .mp4 ). Как передать их по отдельности знаю, а можно ли передать сразу все файлы одним запросом используя Retrofit. Либо с помощью других библиотек.

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/34792503/3212712

Comment: А как Вы реализовали выбор файла? К примеру мне необходимо выбрать фото из галереи и закачать его, сейчас сижу с проблемой file not found!

Comment: @OlegMiroshin, В моем случае у меня нет выбора файла. я просто записываю видео с камеры и отправляю. Для передачи фото я обычно использую Base64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё оказалось на много проще, чем я думал, просто на сервере не правильно разбирали мой запрос, поэтому я решил, что не могу передавать несколько файлов сразу)

Так описываем запрос для ретрофит:

```
@Multipart
@PUT("/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Header("X-Security-Key") String token,
                          @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
```

Так выполняем:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(LoganSquareConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    final RestAPI service = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);

    List<MultipartBody.Part> files = new ArrayList<>();

    String path = getOutputMarkStorage() + File.separator;

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getVideo_list().size(); i++) {
        File file = new File(path + model.getVideo_list().get(i));
        // create RequestBody instance from file
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        MultipartBody.Part file_body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video" + i, file.getName(), requestFile);

        files.add(file_body);
    }

    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(context.getSharedPreferences("detail", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.TOKEN, "null"),
            files);
```

Answer (score 1):

Интерфейс:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/upload/index.php")
    Observable<Void> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

Модель:

```
Observable<Void> postImage(MultipartBody.Part image, RequestBody name);
```

Выбор файла и загрузка:

```
RxPhoto.requestUri(context,TypeRequest.GALLERY)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(new Action1<Uri>(){

    @Override
    public void call(Uri uri) {

        Log.d(tag, "up => " + uri);
        Log.d(tag, "getPath => " + getPath(context,uri));

        String URL = getPath(context,uri);

        File file = new File( URL+"" );

        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "upload_test");

        GetDataSubscription = model.postImage(body,name)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe();
    }
})
.subscribe();
```

Вспомогательная функция для нахождения файла, тут и была загвоздка, её я нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content/20559418#20559418)

php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));

$file_path = ROOT_DIR . "";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
    echo '{"result": "success"}';
} else{
    echo '{"result": "fail"}';
}
```